# I cant figure out how to get some commands working

Tags: vbscript

I have this script I want to use that acts like an emergency wipe. Whenever I try to execute it to test it out it gives me a error message that says,

```
Script: C:Users\user\Desktop\test.vbs
Line :  3
Char:   1
Error:  The system cannot find the file specified.
Code:   80070002
Source: (null)
```

The code that executes the command I want it to is,

```
strCmd = "cd C:\Windows\system32"
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strCmd

strCmd = "del *"
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strCmd

strCmd = "y"
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strCmd

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
```

This is a very loosely based string of commands as I based it off of another script that is like this one. Said script is only supposed to send a shutdown command into Command Prompt. This is what it is,

```
strCmd = "shutdown -s -t 0 -f"
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strCmd
```

I thought that I could just put the commands to delete sys32 into the shutdown command, and it doesn't work. If anyone has a solution it would be greatly appreciated. I also would like to know if the keypress command I put in at the end would work correctly.

It's probably some really easy fix but its really confusing me.

Comment: Why do you create a new objShell for each command? That doesn't seem right

Comment: @GeertBellekens They don't need multiple instances of the same object they could just instantiate `objShell` once and re-use that. The main issue is they are trying to run `cmd` commands directly from `Run` which won't work.